# Simulating enter key after selecting date (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, datepicker

I've got a form field using the jQuery datepicker function on a Wordpress website using a product customizer plugin.  The form field by default was never intended to be a date picker, I added that later.  While I can get the date picker working fine with the field itself, the only way it'll actually show on the product is if you press enter in the field after selecting the date.  I'd like this to happen automatically so it appears after the user selects a date, or when the datepicker box loses focus.  I've attempted to simulate the enter key being pressed using this but it didn't do anything (console log worked though):

```
   jQuery(function () {
  var e = jQuery.Event( "keydown", { keyCode: 13 } );
        jQuery("#ui-datepicker-div").focusout(function() {
 jQuery("#date-of-birth-field").focus();
 jQuery("#date-of-birth-field").trigger( e );
 console.log("test");
});
```

#ut-datepicker-div is the datpicker calendar element, while #date-of-birth-field is the input ID where the date appears.

Any other way of achieving this?  I also tried the 'load' function but that didn't work either.

Comment: Is it part of a Form where you can trigger a `submit` on the form to simulate the enter?

Comment: have you tried `.click()`? ...even though this feels really hacky, also more code would be helpful in understanding the problem and solution :-)

Comment: @Twisty There is a 'Done' button on the calendar div, which I've also tried hooking into but no luck.  Really any kind of input will automatically have the text show on the product.  Enter, space, etc.

Comment: @Aneuway I feel any kind of solution will end up being hacky, so I don't mind.  Here is the page itself - click the Date of Birth / Death toggle on the right and enter a Date of Brith to see how it work.  The date will show up in the text box but not the product itself unless you press enter.

https://headstones.solutioserver.com/marker-customizer/configure/31985/

Comment: @ev88 kind of hard to figure out. I would advise something in the `onSelect` option: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect It should be the same call as what is done for First / Last Name.

Comment: @Twisty Thanks for your answer below, unfortunately it still doesn't update the product image.  No errors though.

Comment: @ev88 currently, it's too complex to tell when the trigger is it's looking for. It seems there is some other JS bound to it that is updating the image. You'll want to pour over the various scripts to see whats working on First Name and mimic that in `onSelect`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your definition:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#date-of-birth-field, #date-of-death-field, #companioin-2-date-of-birth-field, #companioin-2-date-of-death-field").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "c-100:c+0",
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'M dd yy',
    onSelect: function(dt, obj) {
      $(this).trigger($.Event("keypress", {
        which: 13
      }));
    }
  });

  $("#component-5ed524ac8d83c, #component-5ed671ac50881").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("maxSize");
  });
});
```

When a Date is selected, it should trigger an <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress.